# "database/seeds" error when running "composer global require laravel/valet"

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

I have installed Composer, Laravel, among other things on this server. I'm trying to run:

> composer global require laravel/valet

It attempts to run, and outputs:

> Changed current directory to /home/myUser/.config/composer Using version
>   ^2.9 for laravel/valet ./composer.json has been updated Loading
>   composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies
>   (including require-dev) Nothing to install or update Generating
>   optimized autoload files
>
> In ClassMapGenerator.php line 69:
>                                                                                                            Could not scan for classes inside "database/seeds" which does not
>   appear to be a file nor a folder

Where is/should this folder be, and why wouldn't it already be there anyway?

Comment: Try running `composer update` and then try it again.

Comment: As written in the documentation: "Valet requires macOS" - you cannot expect that it runs on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Valet is a MacOS utility, there are linux ports, [such as this one](https://cpriego.github.io/valet-linux/), but it won't work on Ubuntu as it uses Homebrew under the hood, a package manager for MacOS.

Comment: I'm so confused. I have Laravel installed both on my Mac and on my Ubuntu server. Do I develop on my Mac or on the server? How does developing on my Mac affect what is online? There's nothing I can find about this online.

Comment: Are you trying to install Valet on the ubuntu server as your webserver? Valet is a local development tool, install it on your mac to make your local environment easier but on your actual server you shouldn't use it to host your site. If you've never deployed a website on a server before I'd recommend trying Laravel Forge for now, or at least following the deployment guide https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment

Comment: Thanks. I've developed a lot of sites, just never with Laravel. I'll check out Forge.